# `make` failed with exit code: 2 at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js)

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install

I have certain application which exposes about 100 Soap Web Service Services and I need to "facade" them as Rest Service using NodeJs. In other words, I will create a rest service that will recieve the parameters as json and I will send them to certain Soap Service (same parameters in xml format) and I will transform the answer from xml to json.

It is not part of this question discuss about alternatives for NodeJs neither discuss alternatives to change the client consumer approach to parse soap.

I "googled" a bit and I found a very interesting project at https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap and another at https://github.com/23/node-soap, all of them seeming that depends on same API. Nevertheless, when I tried to install it (npm install soap), I get the error in my question subject.

PS. I using Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
PS2. same error happens when I tried npm i easysoap

```
demetrio@nodejs ~/movie-collection $ sudo npm install soap
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead

> ursa@0.9.4 install /home/demetrio/movie-collection/node_modules/ursa
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/demetrio/movie-collection/node_modules/ursa/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o
make: g++: Command not found
ursaNative.target.mk:92: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory '/home/demetrio/movie-collection/node_modules/ursa/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/demetrio/movie-collection/node_modules/ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:ursa@0.9.4 ursa@0.9.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:ursa@0.9.4 Exit status 1
movie-collection@0.0.1 /home/demetrio/movie-collection
└── soap@0.18.0  extraneous

demetrio@nodejs ~/movie-collection $
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a C++ compiler installed. Is there a `build-essential` package for your distribution? (By the way, the actual error message is `make: g++: Command not found` - the rest is just other programs noting that an error occurred further up.)

Comment: Do you suggest me any specific C++ compiler for who is going to focus on NodeJs and its surrounds or related staffs? (I am not planning to develop efectvely in C)

Comment: I suggest you install `build-essential`.

Comment: I am pretty sure node-gyp relies on python 2.x

Comment: Melpomene and Hiyper, thanks. My final goal is to expose as Rest Service using NodeJs about 100 Soap services developed in Java based on java.ws.rs-api
javax.xml.soap-api
geronimo-jaxws
cxf-*
wsdl4j. So I have to consume soap and publish rest. That said, am I am in good direction when I tried npm install soap? What is node-gyp aimed for?

Comment: Hiyper, I see "g++: Command not found" which I think Melpomene coments make sense as far as I can see. Should I install any package of python in order to properly support node-gyp?

Comment: Melpomene, please addd your answer somehow I can set it as final answer. You have answered 100% my original question (any last comment related to my real goal, expose soap services as rest service via NodeJs will be appreciatted but certainly your answer fixed the issue related to this question)